# throws NoRootNodeMappingException while projecting/mapping neo4j query result to an interface or DTO class

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

my query is very simple and the projection I am doing is following guidelines given in [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces](Spring Data Neo4J Projection) documentation.
My Code:

```
@Query("MATCH (User {mobile:$mobile})-[:CONTACT]-(n:User)-[:STEPTAKER]-(s:Step) RETURN n.name AS name, s.count AS count")
    public List<StepList> findAllStepByMobile(String mobile);
    

interface StepList{
    String getName();
    int getCount();
}
```

The error:
2021-09-10 10:36:25.180 ERROR 18088 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NoRootNodeMappingException: Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside Record<{s.count: 400}> for org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@305b43ca] with root cause

*org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NoRootNodeMappingException: Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside Record<{s.count: 400}> for org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@305b43ca*

Answer (score 0):

If you specify edge types the should have a colon, so
[:STEPTAKER] and [:CONTACT]

Also , when returning multiple columns, separate them by a comma

RETURN a.name AS name,  s.count AS count

Comment: updated according to your suggestion but still shows the same error

Comment: @NoorKhan  does the query run well when executed inside the Neo4j browser?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine there returns two columns name and count.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.2.0/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

From the above link:

"The important bit here is that the properties defined here exactly match properties in the aggregate root"

I think that means your StepList interface has to have a subset of properties from your root class (which I assume is User).